# Changing Directory to different Drive in GitBash for Windows 10

Tags: git-bash, windows-10-desktop

I need to know if i open GitBash in desktop, can I change directory to my local **disk D** from inside GitBash? this will require going backwards and than forwards to **D Drive**, as **Desktop** is present in the **C Drive**.

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

I know I can just go to my folder in **D Drive** and right-click to select GitBash here which is more effecient. But I just need to know because I am on a learning basis.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use `cd d:`?